# Filtering panda dataframe in Python based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, pandas-groupby

So, I've created this dataframe...

```
survey = pd.DataFrame(data=[[ 6893 , 'F' , 23 , 'Mar' , 57126.33 ] ,
                        [ 4198 , 'F' , 57 , 'Res' , 43911.31 ] ,
                        [ 6265 , 'M' , 43 , 'Mar' , 48624.71 ] ,
                        [ 4900 , 'D' , 54 , 'Mar' , 54350.30 ] ,
                        [ 6704 , 'M' , 44 , 'Res' , 35071.43 ] ,
                        [ 9109 , 'D' , 53 , 'Res' , 47676.86 ] ,
                        [ 4528 , 'F' , 24 , 'Man' , 42470.49 ] ,
                        [ 6785 , 'M' , 44 , 'Res' , 52408.86 ] ,
                        [ 3356 , 'F' , 57 , 'Man' , 35537.07 ] ,
                        [ 7469 , 'D' , 54 , 'Man' , 46918.93 ] ,
                        [ 1434 , 'F' , 67 , 'Res' , 50906.68 ] ,
                        [ 8219 , 'D' , 22 , 'Mar' , 48797.58 ] ,
                        [ 1207 , 'M' , 60 , 'Man' , 45230.00 ] ,
                        [ 2362 , 'F' , 55 , 'Man' , 44164.64 ] ,
                        [ 3542 , 'F' , 42 , 'Res' , 48144.46 ] ,
                        [ 1277 , 'F' , 37 , 'Mar' , 49506.02 ] ,
                        [ 9538 , 'M' , 43 , 'Man' , 54627.42 ] ,
                        [ 7313 , 'D' , 62 , 'Man' , 59909.78 ] ,
                        [ 9064 , 'M' , 35 , 'Mar' , 49802.22 ] ,
                        [ 4725 , 'F' , 23 , 'Res' , 55224.95 ] ,
                        [ 2103 , 'M' , 33 , 'Mar' , 46075.63 ] ,
                        [ 7076 , 'M' , 54 , 'Mar' , 43206.42 ] ,
                        [ 9743 , 'F' , 43 , 'Res' , 39168.57 ] ,
                        [ 5148 , 'M' , 59 , 'Res' , 42171.72 ] ,
                        [ 4771 , 'M' , 64 , 'Man' , 60375.02 ] ,
                        [ 6096 , 'F' , 27 , 'Man' , 66510.43 ] ,
                        [ 1088 , 'F' , 56 , 'Res' , 43423.36 ]],
                         columns = ['SSID' , 'Gender' , 'Age' , 'Department' , 'Salary'])
```

I want to use the filter method compute the median salary for employees with an age greater than 50.

I used...

```
def filterf (x):
            return x['Age']. median () > 50

survey.groupby('Salary').filter(filterf).median()
```

But this doesn't return quite what I'm looking for.  Thoughts?

Comment: _But this doesn't return quite what I'm looking for._ What does it return, and how does it differ from what you're looking for? _Thoughts?_ Yes, have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 0):

First filter by age, then apply median on the salary column

survey[survey['Age'] > 50 ]['Salary'].median()

Comment: `survey[survey['Age'] > 50 ]['Salary'].median()` --> `survey.loc[survey['Age'] > 50, 'Salary'].median()`

Comment: that is 200 microseconds faster @AMC

Comment: It's mostly a matter of creating good habits, try executing `survey[survey['Age'] > 50 ]['Salary'] = 0`.